# R and XML -> Importing a data-file

Tags: xml, r, import

I want to put an XML-file into R bij splitting the XML-file into three data-frames.

I've added a part of the XML-file below.

What I want is three separate dataframes, containing the following:

1. One frame containing the variables in node 'Game' and the values of the variables
2. One frame containing the value of the variable 'id' of the node 'Game' in the first column and than the variables from the node 'Event' in the next columns
3. One frame containing the variable "id" from the node 'Event' and the values of the node 'Q' into the next columns.

This would result in a small database in which i can link the data though the key's 'id'.

I've been trying to do this with the XML-package, but just don't get it to work. I think it would be rather straightforward for a XML-experienced user.

Here is a part of the XML-file:

```
<Games timestamp="2013-12-26T12:53:08">
- <Game id="727429" away_team_id="123" away_team_name="Team A" competition_id="99" competition_name="Competition" game_date="2013-09-10" home_team_id="321" home_team_name="Team B" matchday="1" period_1_start="2012-09-10T19:00:42" period_2_start="2012-09-10T20:05:49" season_id="2009" season_name="Season 2009/2010">
- <Event id="1750965992" event_id="1" type_id="34" period_id="16" min="0" sec="0" team_id="118" outcome="1" x="0.0" y="0.0" timestamp="2013-09-10T19:06:02.485" last_modified="2013-09-10T20:39:26">
  <Q id="1508752895" qualifier_id="227" value="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" /> 
  <Q id="467627412" qualifier_id="59" value="12, 17, 19, 16, 2, 15, 8, 20, 14, 11, 10, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 18, 22, 23" /> 
  <Q id="1441747528" qualifier_id="44" value="1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5" /> 
  <Q id="454079800" qualifier_id="130" value="4" /> 
  <Q id="548551137" qualifier_id="194" value="5816" /> 
  <Q id="2130696856" qualifier_id="197" value="15" /> 
  <Q id="940400796" qualifier_id="30" value="12496, 18759, 38411, 19534, 18003, 17861, 5816, 19524, 17926, 49579, 17878, 4232, 88477, 28160, 77390, 12237, 17279, 42892, 52356, 17740, 8432" /> 
  <Q id="741889327" qualifier_id="131" value="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" /> 
  </Event>
- <Event id="196028273" event_id="1" type_id="34" period_id="16" min="0" sec="0" team_id="831" outcome="1" x="0.0" y="0.0" timestamp="2013-09-10T19:16:53.985" last_modified="2013-09-10T20:54:02">
  <Q id="1972309909" qualifier_id="59" value="1, 4, 2, 18, 17, 3, 21, 16, 11, 7, 8, 12, 23, 25, 5, 6, 19, 24, 14, 15, 20, 22" /> 
  <Q id="584907211" qualifier_id="130" value="12" /> 
  <Q id="1500980037" qualifier_id="227" value="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" /> 
  <Q id="466076659" qualifier_id="44" value="1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5" /> 
  <Q id="867938921" qualifier_id="131" value="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0" /> 
  <Q id="944778733" qualifier_id="194" value="33148" /> 
  <Q id="1374777290" qualifier_id="30" value="33148, 48852, 122779, 37269, 48853, 33324, 118749, 7459, 105835, 37265, 42565, 100566, 83425, 119534, 100981, 50902, 119613, 83725, 33176, 33298, 83531, 125510" /> 
  <Q id="525295255" qualifier_id="197" value="48" /> 
  </Event>
- <Event id="1459266330" event_id="2" type_id="32" period_id="1" min="0" sec="0" team_id="118" outcome="1" x="0.0" y="0.0" timestamp="2013-09-10T19:00:42.327" last_modified="2013-09-10T19:00:42">
  <Q id="1757752982" qualifier_id="127" value="Left to Right" /> 
  </Event>
- <Event id="444900728" event_id="2" type_id="32" period_id="1" min="0" sec="0" team_id="831" outcome="1" x="0.0" y="0.0" timestamp="2013-09-10T19:00:42.327" last_modified="2013-09-10T19:00:42">
  <Q id="884925323" qualifier_id="127" value="Right to Left" /> 
  </Event>
 </Game>
</Games>
```

I think for the /Event-node this would be the most logical:

```
sp2 <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, '//game/event'))
```

But this is what I get:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c("",  : 
duplicate subscripts for columns
```

I am an absolute beginner in XML, so if someone can write a bit of code for that's working and I can go on from there (learn and improve) it would be very helpful!

Comment: Well! It is never straightforward the first time! You should add what you have tried!

Comment: Unfortunately "but just don't get it to work" is not a useful desecription of the problem. Please edit your question to include your code and the actual error message.

Comment: I edited my question and hope you can help me out

Answer (score 1):

This should be a good start.

```
library(XML)

doc <- htmlParse(your_file)
## 
game = xpathSApply(doc,'//game',xmlAttrs)
events = xpathSApply(doc,'//game/event',xmlAttrs)
questions = xpathSApply(doc,'//game/event/q',xmlAttrs)
```